# How to setup Mock Server to Test iOS and Android app

Tags: rest, api, ui-automation, mockserver

I have a mobile application running on iOS and Android, I need to create my functional Automated test cases, however for some scenarios I need specific data , so I think a mock server can help on this. I'm not sure how to start with that as I never setup a mock data server, can someone point to the right direction how to start with that?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by mock server.

If you want to make actual network calls you could use services like [myjson.com](http://myjson.com) or [mocky.io](http://mocky.io) to get the specific json.

If you want to simulate the network calls take a look at MockingJay

https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay

it will stub the network calls and return the specified json.

I usually have many .json files in my test target and use MockingJay to stub the network and test the response/failures.